# get value with jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, get

I want to get one value from my section with jquery and I don't know how to do it...
I look some examples and tried something like this but didn't work...

```
  <script>
      var variable = $("#section").val("showpage"); 
      alert(variable);
  </script>
```

For this section:

```
<section id="section" showpage="works"></section>
```

I tried also:

```
var variable = $(this).attr("showpage");
```

but didn't work neither.

Someone please could help me?! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this: http://api.jquery.com/attr/. And if we use it on your code, should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <section id="section" showpage="works"></section>

    <script>

        // $(document).ready() should be the main starting point. 

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var variable = $("#section").attr("showpage"); 
            alert(variable);
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of ways you can get value from `Html` element and here are few ways you can do so.

Few thing to remember to get values from a `DOM`. This should be inside after page load function `$(document).ready(function(){})` or some kind of a event like `click`,`change` etc as `$('selector').click(function(){})`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// Get value from method 1 using text();
var val_1 = $('#get-value-method-1').text();
console.log(val_1);

// Get value from method 2 using html();
var val_2 = $('#get-value-method-2').html();
console.log(val_2);

// Get value from method 3 using attr() / data();
var val_3_1 = $('#get-value-method-3').attr('data-id');
console.log(val_3_1 );
var val_3_2 = $('#get-value-method-3').data('id');
console.log(val_3_2);


// Get value from method 4 using val();
var val_4 = $('#get-value-method-4').val();
console.log(val_4);


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="get-value-method-1">1000</div>
<div id="get-value-method-2"><span> 2000</span></div>
<div id="get-value-method-3" data-id="3000"></div>
<input type="text" id="get-value-method-4" value="4000" />
```

Comment: Thanks! this clarified a lot of things... and this helped me to track another errors too by the consol log!

Comment: Good to know, that this answer helps you somehow. Happy coding buddy.. !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it after the `dom` loaded,which means do within `$(document).ready()`

Also,I would advice you use `text()` instead of `val()`

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#section").text("showpage"); 
      });
  </script>
```